# Type separation (API design)

Tags: api, oop, design-patterns

Say you design an API for some library.

You want to expose some data type (say `Person`) in the API (e.g. `getAllPeople()`).

Consider the following goals:

- make it easy to add members to the `Person` (extensible)
- don't introduce a dependency between the client of the library, and your implementation (coupling)
- `Person` is likely to include internal state information that is not interesting to the client of the library

How would you go about it?

1. Define the `Person` in the library header / API package; have both the client of the library and the implementation depend on it (high coupling; very easy to extend)
2. Define `Person` in the API/header; define `PersonModel extends Person` in your library implementation (easy to extend; still some coupling)
3. Define `PersonModel` in the impl.; define `Person extends PersonModel` in the API (awful dependencies)
4. Define `PersonModel` in the impl; define `Person` in the API and copy the contents when needed (hard to extend; no coupling)
5. anything else?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, Person is part of the API. It is the responsibility of the library user to choose how to decouple your API in the context of his architecture. You should not impose it.

If the user does not want to use your Person object, he has to encapsulate / copy your object.

Of course you can design Person to be extensible, but in any case it is part of the API. A user of this API is coupled to it. He has to choose when and where he needs to decouple from it and the way to do it. If Person is well designed, he might just use it everywhere. If it is poorly designed or not easy to use/extend, well he will copy the interesting part and redesign it.

When you design an API, the 'Person' kind of object should be an interface e.g. the user should not have access to the implementation. If person is an input to a service of your API, any implementation should work (Liskov principle). If Person is an output parameter, the user should get a reference, with any underlying internal implementation, there will be no coupling with the client code. It is hard when dealing with object construction, but using the *factory design patterns, you can manage even that. If there is no concrete implementation visible to the client code, you have a good API :-)

Comment: I added a constraint to refine the question

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am wondering whether I over-simplified the question, as I don't feel I have a solution yet. How about if the `Person` object must be serializable so it can be used in RPC? The client then _must_ have a concrete class definition of `Person`

Comment: (+1) The first paragraph summarizes the answer ;-)